# OpenLDAP System requirements for virtualization

Tags: virtualization, openldap, system-requirements

I'm looking for the minimum "hardware" requirements for a virtual machine to set up an OpenLDAP server.
I only found software documentation about this, but there is none about hardware, except that it requieres very little requirements.
Has someone did some research on this topic, or has any data or examples of actual OpenLDAP implementations?
I'm planning on using a Linux CentOS as OS.

Comment: Off topic, but my OpenLAP server has been running for 9 years, several weeks since last reboot, and its VM ion Windows is 39M. Not a large DIT but it gives you a data point.

Comment: I know it's an old question but it's ranking high in search results, so I'll add my datapoint: I was testing OpenLDAP in an LXC container on Ubuntu with 150,000 users and the slapd daemon seems to stay between 200-300MB of resident memory, and used 377MB of disk space for the actual mdb database file.  
If I remember correctly my jmeter tests showed 9-11ms average response time for 10 concurrent users (this is local machine connections, no network time).